# Rails relation.count does not equal relation.map(&:id).count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I cant for the life of me figure out why the below active record relation returns a different result if you run count on the relation directly as opposed to mapping over the relation and then counting the result.

Shouldn't they be the same? Does anyone know what is going on?

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.query_cache.clear
# => {}
Panel.connection.schema_cache.clear!
# => nil
Panel.reset_column_information
# => nil
@filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].map(&:panel_id).count
# => 57
@filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].all.count
  (13.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "panels" WHERE "panels"."agglo_code_id" = $1 AND "panels"."environment_id" = $2 AND "panels"."product_id" = $3 AND "panels"."alcohol_friendly" = $4 AND "panels"."suburb" = 'Marrickville' AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 52)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "AIDAAU_Avails" WHERE "AIDAAU_Avails"."PanelID" = panels.panel_uid AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."TillDate" >= '2017-08-21 00:00:00.000000' AND "AIDAAU_Avails"."FromDate" <= '2017-09-03 00:00:00.000000')) LIMIT 100) subquery_for_count  [["agglo_code_id", 4], ["environment_id", 2], ["product_id", 1], ["alcohol_friendly", "t"]]
# => 0
```

Shouldn't `@filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].map(&:panel_id).count` be equal to `@filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].count`?

The relation itself seems to actually contain all the records:

```
[3] pry(#<PanelSearch>)> @filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code]
=> [#<Panel:0x007fe4ef779990
  location_type: "Street",
  move_id: "27779",
  panel_id: "11441A1",
  address: "Victoria Rd N/O Sydenham Rd E/S",
  postal_code: "2204",
  suburb: "Marrickville",
  latitude: #<BigDecimal:7fe4ee0b14b0,'-0.33909329E2',18(27

[5] pry(#<PanelSearch>)> @filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].class
=> Panel::ActiveRecord_Relation

[6] pry(#<PanelSearch>)> @filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].to_sql
=> "SELECT  \"panels\".* FROM \"panels\" WHERE \"panels\".\"agglo_code_id\" = 4 AND \"panels\".\"environment_id\" = 2 AND \"panels\".\"product_id\" = 1 AND \"panels\".\"alcohol_friendly\" = 't' AND \"panels\".\"suburb\" = 'Marrickville' AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 52)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM \"AIDAAU_Avails\" WHERE \"AIDAAU_Avails\".\"PanelID\" = panels.panel_uid AND \"AIDAAU_Avails\".\"TillDate\" >= '2017-08-21 00:00:00.000000' AND \"AIDAAU_Avails\".\"FromDate\" <= '2017-09-03 00:00:00.000000')) LIMIT 500"
[7] pry(#<PanelSearch>)> @filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].all.to_sql
=> "SELECT  \"panels\".* FROM \"panels\" WHERE \"panels\".\"agglo_code_id\" = 4 AND \"panels\".\"environment_id\" = 2 AND \"panels\".\"product_id\" = 1 AND \"panels\".\"alcohol_friendly\" = 't' AND \"panels\".\"suburb\" = 'Marrickville' AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM campaign_search_panels WHERE campaign_search_panels.panel_id = panels.panel_id AND campaign_search_panels.campaign_id = 52)) AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM \"AIDAAU_Avails\" WHERE \"AIDAAU_Avails\".\"PanelID\" = panels.panel_uid AND \"AIDAAU_Avails\".\"TillDate\" >= '2017-08-21 00:00:00.000000' AND \"AIDAAU_Avails\".\"FromDate\" <= '2017-09-03 00:00:00.000000')) LIMIT 500"
```

Comment: What does `@filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code]` by itself print?

Comment: Other prints that would help are `@filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].to_sql` and `@filtered_skew_panels[agglo_code].all.to_sql`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've added more info above.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Panel class, what does `@filtered_skew_panels.inspect` print out?

Comment: Hi Andrew. Panel is just an active record object. Basically @filtered_skew_panels is an active record relation containing panel records